# Generic result to key value list or dictionary in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, collections, key-value

I need to return a key value paired list of state (region) names with their abbreviated value within my DNN install.  In my function below I successfully obtain my desired results to an inferred variable named RegionList, however I cannot cast these results to a key value paired list or dictionary and return the result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function GetRegionPerCountry(CountryCode As String) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
    Dim lc As New DotNetNuke.Common.Lists.ListController()
    Dim countryID As Integer
    Dim RegionList2 As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))

    If Not CountryCode Is Nothing Then
        Dim entryCollection As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of DotNetNuke.Common.Lists.ListEntryInfo)
        entryCollection = lc.GetListEntryInfoItems("Country")
        countryID = entryCollection.Where(Function(x) x.Value = CountryCode).Select(Function(x) x.EntryID).FirstOrDefault()

        entryCollection = lc.GetListEntryInfoItems("Region")
        Dim RegionList = entryCollection.Where(Function(x) x.ParentID = countryID).Select(Function(x) New With {.Key = x.Text.ToString(), .Value = x.Value.ToString()}).ToList()
        RegionList2 = RegionList
    End If
    Return RegionList2
End Function
```

Comment: Try *Return RegionList2.Key.Tostring()*

Comment: Whoops,  you want a list not a string itself. I would do a breakpoint and make sure the regionList is the type of variable you expect it to be.